# GPG Key not available for Local Apt Repo

Tags: apt, gpg

We have an Apt-mirror server. 
We have also a custom repo named 'local' on this server.

If I add in sources.list the following line :

```
deb http://aptmirror.example.com/local trusty main
```

The following error is displayed :

```
W: Erreur de GPG : http://aptmirror.example.com trusty InRelease : The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available : NO_PUBKEY 2ED3267B70B1ADC4
```

Even with the following command :

```
gpg --keyserver aptmirror.example.com --recv-keys 2ED3267B70B1ADC4
gpgkeys: key 2ED3267B70B1ADC4 can't be retrieved
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

I tried also with `apt-key adv` but it's not working..

Do you know how to have this local GPG Public key available for all Linux clients ?

---

**Attempts**

```
gpg --send-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com $GPGKEY
```

or

```
gpg --send-keys --keyserver keys.gnupg.net $GPGKEY
```

but I got :

```
gpgkeys: this keyserver type only supports key retrieval
gpg: keyserver internal error
gpg: keyserver send failed: keyserver error
```

And Copy-Paste with `gpg --export --armor` is not really a solution, with 200 computers

EDIT : 
Thanks for your answers.

I tried this :

```
gpg --send-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com $GPGKEY
```

OR

```
gpg --send-keys --keyserver keys.gnupg.net $GPGKEY
```

but I got :

```
gpgkeys: this keyserver type only supports key retrieval
gpg: keyserver internal error
gpg: keyserver send failed: keyserver error
```

And Copy-Paste with `gpg --export --armor` is not really a solution, with 200 computers ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that `aptmirror.example.com` sounds like an apt mirror server, not a GPG key server?

Usually you'd upload your key to a public key server like subkeys.pgp.net, but that's not sufficient to establish trust.

Answer (score 0):

On the mirror do:

```
gpg --export --armor
```

Select the key and on the client machine do:

```
apt-key add -[ENTER]
[PASTE KEY][ENTER]
[Ctrl-D]
```

OR

On the mirror publish the key to keyservers

```
gpg --send-keys
```

and than:

```
gpg --recv-keys 2ED3267B70B1ADC4
```

on the client. You may have to wait for a couple of minutes between publishing the key and it becomes available on the keyservers.